# Scroll bar in firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, scrollbar

I have a Javascript code that opens a pop-up windows which contains a table. The problem is that table contains too many rows to be displayed on the screen area. On IE and Chrome i have a scroll bar to move up and down, but on Firefox i don't.
This is the javascript code:

```
    function openWindowInsertResp() {
     .............
dropDownValueA + "&subactivityID=" + dropDownValueS, "PartialTask", "status = 1,height = auto,width = 900,top = 100,left=250,resizable = 1");
.............
    }
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<table style="border:none; width:100%;">
<tr>
<th style="text-align:center;">
No.</th>
<th style="text-align:center;">Description</th></tr>
@{
    int i=1;
    foreach (Project.Domain.Entities.Labor_JobDesc cr in contracts)
    {
        <tr style="border:none">
        <td style="text-align:center; width:2%;">@i</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
         <textarea cols="auto"; rows="auto"; style="width:100%;"; readonly="readonly"> @cr.Res</textarea>
        </td>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }
}
</table>
```

What I have to do to have a scroll bar on Firefox? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
window.open(adress, '....other params..., scrollbars = yes')
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding 'scrollbars=1' to your window.open options:

```
window.open(url, name, "status = 1, ... ,resizable = 1, scrollbars=1");
```

Comment: Both answers are correct, but I will accept the first one (like FIFO)

Comment: yes, @Reinder's answer is earlier, athough i can't figure out how did that happen, cuz i checked if there are answers just before posting mine.

Comment: not sure what happend then, but both answers are pretty clear so it's OK